# Uninitialized Constant in Rails Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

I have the following in my controller:

```
class SurveysController < ApplicationController

  def index
    survey_provider = FluidSurveysProviders::SurveyProvider.new
    contact_lists = survey_provider.get_lists()
    @survey = Survey.new(contact_lists)
  end
```

And I'm receiving this error:

```
NameError in SurveysController#index
uninitialized constant SurveysController::FluidSurveysProviders
```

Excuse my Rails noobiness, I'm sure I'm leaving out something important here. But it seems to me that I am trying to "initialize" the constant with this line:

`survey_provider = FluidSurveysProviders::SurveyProvider.new`

But that's the same line that's throwing an error because it's not initialized. Where should I be "initializing" the Provider?

Answer (score 1):

Once you `require fluid_surveys_providers` (or similar) then do this:

`include FluidSurveysProviders`

Comment: I did not. When I `include FluidSurveysProviders` I get this:

`ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant SurveysController::FluidSurveysProviders)` instead of the `NameError`

Comment: Forgot to mention you need to `require` the file too.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure SurveyProvider is wrapped with module FluidSurveysProviders.  It may look like this

```
module FluidSurveysProviders
  class SurveyProvider
    ...
  end
end
```

if its an ActiveRecord object try this

```
class FluidSurveysProviders::SurveyProvider < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The `SurveyProvider` was not loaded correctly.

1. For a quick fix, move the class file into `app` directory, e.g. `app/lib/survey_provider.rb`. Then all code inside `app` will be auto-loaded by Rails.
2. Or make sure the path to `class SurveyProvider` is included in the autoload_path of Rails. In **config/application.rb**

   `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib) # where lib is directory to survery_provider`

   If you use Rails 5, be careful that autoload is disabled in production environment. Check this [link for more info.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38198668/rails-5-load-lib-files-in-production)