# Load lib files in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autoload, ruby-on-rails-5

I've upgraded one of my apps from Rails 4.2.6 to Rails 5.0.0. The [Upgrade Guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#autoloading-is-disabled-after-booting-in-the-production-environment) says, that the Autoload feature is now disabled in production by default.

Now I always get an error on my production server since I load all lib files with autoload in the `application.rb` file.

```
module MyApp
    class Application < Rails::Application
        config.autoload_paths += %W( lib/ )
    end
end
```

For now, I've set the `config.enable_dependency_loading` to `true` but I wonder if there is a better solution to this. There must be a reason that Autoloading is disabled in production by default.

Comment: crazy thing, and docs still tell you to do auto_load. I was very confused what is going wrong in production env for a new app. And since I started learning with Rails 5 I didn't read migration guide. I filed a doc issue to hopefully get this resolved: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/27268

Comment: amazingly, I have two files in `lib` dir, one file is easily available in Runtime, but another has to be required manually :D

Comment: @Tobias What solution did you end up with?

Comment: @geoboy I group code (like `Validators`) in folders directly in the app/ directory since code there is auto loaded.

Comment: it's about **proper file path and class definition** here is what work for me in Rails 5.2: File path: `app/services/paylinx/paylinx_service.rb` Class definition: `module Paylinx class PaylinxService end end`. I tried these `autoload_paths` stuff. doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Autoloading is disabled in the production environment because of thread safety. Thank you to @Зелёный for the link.

I solved this problem by storing the lib files in a `lib` folder in my `app` directory as recommended on [Github](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13142). Every folder in the `app` folder gets loaded by Rails automatically.

Comment: If you don't want to dig through long discussion thread on Github, you can find distilled explanation here: http://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2016/07/22/solutions-to-potential-upgrade-problems-in-rails-5/

Comment: I used `config.eager_load_paths << "#{Rails.root}/lib"`, that's better IMO to follow recommended rails app structure.

Comment: Putting lib in `app/lib` is recommended by rails members
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13142#issuecomment-275549669

Comment: This completely ruins what the purpose of `lib` is. I'd wait for tenderlove or DHH to chime in. In the meantime, I'd (personally) recommend sticking with @Lev Lukomsky's answer.

Comment: @JoshBrody My opinion now is that you shouldn't need the `/lib` directory at all. Third party libs are most of the time gems and if not there should be a gem created. For other files, I create specific folders in the `/app` directory. For example `validators`.

Comment: I agree! I think that all business logic should belong in `/app`; I guess what I'm getting at is if you're writing a Rescue extension or have some non-domain-specific objects that extend ActiveModel, where should that belong? My first instinct tells me `lib`

Comment: I think (after getting it wrong on many projects) that `/lib` is meant for functionality that could be separate gems (don't require anything in app or the environment or database) but aren't (yet) -- a kind of staging point. However I find there is always app-related utility functionality that doesn't quite fit in any of the existing `/app/*` structures -- that goes well in `/app/lib` and then these are good candidates for refactoring (abstracting into app, or pulling apart into something else)

Answer (score 178):

My list of changes after moving to Rails 5:

1. Place `lib` dir into `app` because all code inside app is *autoloaded* in dev and *eager loaded* in prod and most importantly is *autoreloaded* in development so you don't have to restart server each time you make changes.
2. Remove any `require` statements pointing to your own classes inside `lib` because they all are autoloaded anyway if their file/dir naming are correct, and if you leave `require` statements it can break autoreloading. More info [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html)
3. Set `config.eager_load = true` in all environments to see code loading problems eagerly in dev.
4. Use `Rails.application.eager_load!` before playing with threads to avoid "circular dependency" errors.
5. If you have any ruby/rails extensions then leave that code inside old `lib` directory and load them manually from initializer. This will ensure that extensions are loaded before your further logic that can depend on it:

   ```
   # config/initializers/extensions.rb
   Dir["#{Rails.root}/lib/ruby_ext/*.rb"].each { |file| require file }
   Dir["#{Rails.root}/lib/rails_ext/*.rb"].each { |file| require file }
   ```

Comment: So how does one uses the ```lib``` folder now? I mean moving ```lib``` dir into ```app``` dir seems kind of like a workaround.

Comment: `/app/lib/`placed a file/class and it's NOT autoloading. tested in rails 5.1, new project

Comment: It's worth noting that you need to stop spring.  I moved everything to app/lib/ and then wasted a little time wondering why I still couldn't use my classes from the console.  spring stop ftw :)

Comment: Where would the following line go `Rails.application.eager_load!`

Comment: @Lev: When I do that, I see the following error in `dev`: `NameError - uninitialized constant ApplicationController::JsonWebToken:` Do you know what might be going on?

Comment: @geoboy that's when the file is not loaded. it looks like the file is searched first in the root context as in `::ModuleOrClass` and then the current context, say, `ApplicationController::ModuleOrClass` where it's called. Your error is showing the second result.

Comment: This may work but it isn't the best solution. The folder structure is semantic as well. Things in `lib` have a different perceived closeness to the project than things in the `app` directory. Several of the other answers are better than this one.

Comment: Good suggestion for config.eager_load = true, but bad suggestion on moving lib into app.

Comment: @CWitty `lib` is semantic for gems, but for Rails app it's rather unexpected to to have some ruby code in `lib` and all other code in `app` like `controllers`/`mailers`/`jobs`/`interactors`/`policies`/`serializers`/`decorators`/`helpers`/...

Comment: If lib is supposed for code agnostic to the app, where is it supposed to place additional classes related to project but not to a model? (e.g Algorithms tied to the app) ?

Answer (score 119):

I just used `config.eager_load_paths` instead of `config.autoload_paths` like mention akostadinov on github comment:
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13142#issuecomment-275492070

```
# config/application.rb
...
# config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
```

It works on development and production environment.

Thanks [Johan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3982562/johan-wentholt) for suggestion to replace `#{Rails.root}/lib` with `Rails.root.join('lib')`!

Comment: Works like a charm. I didn't like the syntax so changed it to `config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')`.

Comment: To me that was the best answer. My project began on Rails 5.2 from scratch and the folder /lib was still created outside the /app folder. I didn't see a good reason to move it.

Comment: Yep, this works! Seems Rails devs really enjoy causing lib loading issues :D until next time!

Comment: To Rails 5.2 uses `config.eager_load_paths += [Rails.root.join('lib')]` instead because  `config.eager_load_paths` is a frozen array

Comment: @WilliamWongGaray config.eager_load_paths is read-only when you try to modify it in initializer. When you add paths in `application.rb` it will work using both methods.

Answer (score 24):

> There must be a reason that Autoloading is disabled in production by
>   default.

Here is a long discussion about this issue. https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13142

Comment: This discussion is the best, though a lengthy read, source of information on the subject that I've come across.

Answer (score 13):

This allows to have lib autoreload, and works in production environment too.

P.S. I have changed my answer, now it adds to both eager- an autoload paths, regardless of environment, to allow work in custom environments too (like stage)

```
# config/initializers/load_lib.rb
...
config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
...
```

Comment: Could you expand on why this fixes the issue?

Comment: @Stuart.Sklinar this allows to have lib autoreload, and works in production environment too. P.S. I have changed my answer, now it adds to both eager- an autoload paths, regardless of environment, to allow work in custom environments too (like stage)

Comment: Could you expand (In your answer)?

Code only answer's don't really help anyone understand why it should be done "that way" - I should add I'm not a Ruby dev, just helping clear up SO. Adding some commentary to a "code only answer" would give it some actual context.

Comment: @Stuart.Sklinar sure

Answer (score 10):

Just change **config.autoload_paths** to **config.eager_load_paths** in config/application.rb file. Because in rails 5 autoloading is disabled for production environment by default. For more details please follow the [link](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/08/29/rails-5-disables-autoloading-after-booting-the-app-in-production.html).

```
 #config.autoload_paths << "#{Rails.root}/lib"
  config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
```

It works for both environment development and production.

Answer (score 5):

In some sense, here is a unified approach in Rails 5 to centralize eager and autoload configuration, in the same time it adds required autoload path whenever eager load is configured otherwise it won't be able to work correctly:

```
# config/application.rb
...
config.paths.add Rails.root.join('lib').to_s, eager_load: true

# as an example of autoload only config
config.paths.add Rails.root.join('domainpack').to_s, autoload: true
...
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone struggled with this like me, it's not enough to just place a directory under `app/`. Yes, you'll get autoloading but not necessary [reloading, which requires namespacing conventions to be fulfilled](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/14382#issuecomment-65228243).

Also, using initializer for loading old root-level `lib` will prevent reloading feature during development.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that some dependencies belong in `lib` and some may belong in `app/lib`.

I prefer to load all files I've chosen to put in `lib` for all environments, hence I do this in `config/application.rb` immediately after requiring the bundle but before opening the `MyApplicationName` module.

```rb
# load all ruby files in lib
Dir[File.expand_path('../../lib/**/*.rb', __FILE__)].each { |file| require file }
```

This doesn't depend on `Rails.root` (which isn't defined yet), and doesn't depend on eager loading (which may be off for an environment).

Answer (score 2):

## config.autoload_lib (Rails 7.1+)

Starting from **Rails 7.1**, there is a new configuration method, [config.autoload_lib(ignore:)](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/48572).

It significantly simplifies the loading of the `lib` folder.

```rb
# config/application.rb
config.autoload_lib(ignore: ["assets", "tasks", "generators"])
```

**Sources:**

- [Introducing config.autoload_lib and config.autoload_lib_once for Enhanced Autoloading](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/7_1_release_notes.html#introducing-config-autoload-lib-and-config-autoload-lib-once-for-enhanced-autoloading).
- [Introduce config.autoload_lib](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/48572).
- [def autoload_lib](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.1.0.rc1/railties/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb#L464).

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that worked for me is adding the nested lib path in eager load paths AND adding a require_dependency in a config.to_prepare block.

```
# application.rb
...
config.to_prepare do
  require_dependency("#{Rails.root}/lib/spree/core/product_filters.rb")
end

config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join('lib').join('spree').join('core')
...
```

Comment: This worked for me as well, whereas just modifying `eager_load_paths` did not. It does seem to me however that the require_dependency could benefit from using the join methods as well, i.e. `require_dependency(Rails.root.join('lib').join('spree').join('core').join('product_filters.rb'))`

Answer (score 0):

Moving the lib folder to app helped solve a problem, my Twitter api would not run in production. I had "uninitialized constant TwitterApi" and my Twitter API was in my lib folder. 
I had `config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/lib"]` in my application.rb but it didn't work before moving the folder.

This did the trick

Answer (score -8):

to summarize Lev's answer: `mv lib app` was enough to have all my `lib` code autoloaded / auto-reloaded.

(rails 6.0.0beta3 but should work fine on rails 5.x too)