# cannot load such file -- rails_service_helpers/base_meta_resource_controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-api

I'm getting this error in my application.

```
cannot load such file -- rails_service_helpers/base_meta_resource_controller
```

I'm using puma to run the application. I require this service in my code. I use :

```
require 'rails_service_helpers/base_meta_resource_controller'
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried moving your whole `rails_service_helpers` directory somewhere inside of `app` to make sure it auto-loads.

If I were you I'd move `base_meta_resource_controller.rb` into `app/controllers` and call it a day.

If you can't do that, make sure your directory is configured to auto-load. This answer has several ways of accomplishing that: [Rails 5: Load lib files in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38198668/rails-5-load-lib-files-in-production)