# Rails 5.2 & Bootsnap: NameError while using app/lib file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I just upgraded to Rails 5.2 and have run into the following issues in development mode, while using a class `JsonWebToken` from my `app/lib` folder in my `ApplicationController`.

```
NameError - uninitialized constant ApplicationController::JsonWebToken:
```

Following the directions listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40019108/4813012), I have the following notable things:

1. I'm using bootsnap that comes by default with Rails 5.2
2. I no longer have a `require` at the top of `ApplicationController` since files within the `app` folder seem to be auto-required.
3. In my `development.rb`, I have `config.eager_load = false`.
4. In my `application.rb`, I have the following eager and auto loading code:

   ```
   autoloads lib & policy folder during production
   config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
   config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join('policies')

   #autoloads lib & policy folder during development
   config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
   config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('policies')
   ```

---

If I remove `bootsnap`, then I have to add `require 'JsonWebToken'` at the top of `ApplicationController`, and then everything works. Bootsnap didn't like that require statement at the top.

I am not sure what is the right way to be creating or using your own classes in Rails 5.2, and to set up so that they are loaded properly in both development and production. I have gone through the Rails docs, but am extremely unclear.

Comment: Did you run `$ spring stop`...I ran into a similar issue and this fixed it. Also, the "rails way" is to use application.rb as you have done, instead of using require statements.

Comment: Yes, spring was already stopped. In theory, does the above look good?

Comment: Do you have an `include JsonWebToken` in your `ApplicationController`? Try to change it to `include ::JsonWebToken`.