# Use ApplicationHelper in in lib/file.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a file in `lib/thing.rb`, and in there I need to call a method defined in `ApplicationHelper` inside a class method in `thing.rb`

In other words in `Thing.some_method()` it calls `format_me()` in `ApplicationHelper`

I've tried every conceivable way I can think of to `extend ApplicationHelper` or `extend ActionView::Helpers::ApplicationHelper` and it just keeps saying uninitialized constant. Ive also tried `Rails.application.helpers` but I don't know how to access the method in there...

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Can you give some more info, such as _when_ are you calling this, and what the code looks like?

Comment: I am not fully aware of Rails autoloading crap, but I am pretty sure old good plain ruby `require_relative "../app/helpers/..."` would do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're getting errors about uninitialized constants then you can probably resolve the issue by [moving `lib/` into `app/`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40019108/3784008). Using Ruby 2.6.3 and Rails 5.2.3, given the following files and layout:

```
# app/helpers/application_helper.rb
module ApplicationHelper
  def baz
    SecureRandom.uuid
  end
end
```

and:

```
# app/lib/foo.rb
class Foo
  extend ApplicationHelper

  def self.bar
    baz
  end
end
```

Calling `Foo.bar` returns:

```
=> "b6322675-47b2-4ae8-a19a-ffd4af8d6f84"
```