# Rails 6 Autoload Not Finding Class

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-6, zeitwerk

I'm attempting to upgrade from Rails 5 to 6. I did the upgrade steps including adding this:

```
# config/application.rb
config.load_defaults 6.0
```

I have this class:

```
# lib/notification/auto_thank.rb
module Notification
  class AutoThank
    def perform
      # stuff
    end
  end
end
```

Which is used in a task:

```
namespace :notify do
  task auto_thank: :environment do
    Notification::AutoThank.new.perform
  end
end
```

When I do `puts config.autoload_paths`, it's listed, so I expect it to autoload:

`/my/app/path/lib/notification/auto_thank.rb`

But when I run the task I get an error:

> NameError: uninitialized constant Notification

It gets stranger. When I add a require to the task:

```
task auto_thank: :environment do
  require '/my/app/path/lib/notification/auto_thank.rb'
  Notification::AutoThank.new.perform
end
```

I get a different error:

> NameError: expected file /my/app/path/lib/notification/auto_thank.rb to define constant AutoThank, but didn't

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

If you can, locate your auto-loading code in `app/`. As of Rails 6 everything in there will be automatically part of the auto-load path. Rails 5 was more selective.

In this case call it: `app/notifications/notification/auto_thank.rb`

The first part of the path is ignored. The second (optional) part is the namespace.

> Note that to get this to show up in the auto-loader you may need to stop the Spring process with `spring stop`. This must be done any time you introduce a new `app/...` path.

Comment: I would assume that the same issue will happen for everything in lib. I don't think I want to move my whole lib into app. There must be a way to autoload from lib, right?

Comment: You can add it to the auto-load path but the best approach is to put it into `app/` where it belongs. The old `lib/` approach is bound to be deprecated soon and is [not without problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38198668/rails-5-load-lib-files-in-production).