# redmine plugin 500 error for undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

I have write a simple redmine plugin: **myplugin**. and after i installed it into redmine/plugins and got **500** error for not finding the plugin's controller's method in **erb** file..
Anyone can give me some tips? thanks in advance.

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 412ms (ActiveRecord: 20.0ms)

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `get_myplugin_settings' for #<#<Class:0x000055721fbd6028>:0x000055721fbe43d0>):
    1: <% # =============================================================================================== %>
    2: <% #  %>
    3: <% # =============================================================================================== %>
    4: <% get_myplugin_settings %>
    5: <% # =============================================================================================== %>
    6: <% #  %>
    7: <% # =============================================================================================== %>
  plugins/redmine_myplugin/app/views/myplugin/_base_header.html.erb:4:in `_plugins_redmine_myplugin_app_views_myplugin__base_header_html_erb___2359391058711533495_70090861523740'
  lib/redmine/hook/view_listener.rb:59:in `block (2 levels) in render_on'
  lib/redmine/hook/view_listener.rb:57:in `map'
  lib/redmine/hook/view_listener.rb:57:in `block in render_on'
  lib/redmine/hook.rb:61:in `block (2 levels) in call_hook'
  lib/redmine/hook.rb:61:in `each'
  lib/redmine/hook.rb:61:in `block in call_hook'
  lib/redmine/hook.rb:58:in `tap'
  lib/redmine/hook.rb:58:in `call_hook'
  lib/redmine/hook.rb:96:in `call_hook'
  app/views/layouts/base.html.erb:16:in `_app_views_layouts_base_html_erb___1535768041638194131_46974324074020'
  lib/redmine/sudo_mode.rb:63:in `sudo_mode'
```

Comment: btw, I server the redmine app via Nginx. Donnot know if that's related with this problem.

Comment: Where did you define `get_myplugin_settings` ?

Comment: @demir 
In my `application helper patch` file located in `lib` dir:

```
require 'application_helper'

module MyPluginApplicationHelperPatch
  def self.included(base)
    base.send(:include, InstanceMethods)
  end

  module InstanceMethods

    def get_myplugin_settings()
      // …..
    end

  end
end

unless ApplicationHelper.included_modules.include? MyPluginApplicationHelperPatch
  ApplicationHelper.send(:include, MyPluginApplicationHelperPatch)
end
```

Comment: Have you added lib dir to autoload_paths?

Comment: @demir sorry but what does `add lib dir to autoload_paths` exactly mean?

Comment: The module you added to the lib file needs to be loaded. Chek this links: 1- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38198668/rails-5-load-lib-files-in-production
2- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098663/auto-loading-lib-files-in-rails-4

Comment: @demir thanks. your links gave me a great help.