# Uninitialized Constant Error When Switching To Zeitwerk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zeitwerk

I currently have the following files in the `jobs` directory:

```
# app/jobs/importer.rb
module Imporer
  def self.valid_importers
    # Do stuff
  end
end

# app/jobs/importer/custom_import_job.rb
class Importer::CustomImportJob < ApplicationJob
  def perform
    # Do stuff
  end
end
```

This works without issues using the classic code loader, but when switching to Zeitwerk, I get a `NameError: uninitialized constant Importer::CustomImportJob` error when running `rails zeitwerk:check`.

I tried moving `custom_import_job.rb` to the `jobs` directory, but still received the same error. Adding `app/jobs/importer` to `config.autoload_paths` didn't help either.

Is there something wrong with the file structure or am I missing something in the Zeitwerk settings?

Answer (score 6):

After some digging around, I realized that I had the following in `development.rb`:

```
Dir[Rails.root.join('app/jobs/importer/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }
```

It seems this was the cause of the issue. Everything is working as expected now that it's removed!

Comment: What was the problem though? Why was that an issue?

Comment: My guess is that the manual `require` interfered with the way Zeitwerk auto-loads the files, this causing the issue I faced. It probably wouldn't have been a problem if the files weren't in a folder that gets auto-loaded.

Comment: The original problem statement is strange. First, you don't need to touch the autoload paths. Second, if those require ran successfully, Zeitwerk would just ignore the files, because their constants are already in memory (and they would be ignored on reload to, they would not be reloaded even if edited). I suspect there had to be something else. You can eager load directories with `eager_load_dir` instead when the loader is ready, but that is another topic.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else is coming here, sharing some links and context I learned via the Rails troubleshooting guide posted in another answer:

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#troubleshooting

My Rails app is on 7.0, and therefore only has zeitwerk loading. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/classic_to_zeitwerk_howto.html#applications-running-rails-7

Running `rails zeitwerk:check` revealed the problem I was seeing on CI, but not locally because `development.rb` has `config.eager_load = false` set in this project.

My issue was a file I had added under `lib`, conflicting with some deprecated `config.eager_load_paths` additions in `application.rb`.

To solve this though, it turns out my thinking to add a file to `lib` was outdated, and I should have just added it under `app/lib`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39024296/2506034 Then I didn't need any extra `require path/to/where/it/was/in/lib` in my problem-causing file, and the constant was autoloaded instead via being under `app`.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look if you app/jobs is in the path:

```rb
ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths
```

extend by `config.autoload_paths` in `config/application.rb` if necessary.

More debugging information: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#troubleshooting.

- Stop Spring. Restart the server. May also help.

Hope these helps.