# How to initialize Ruby class instance variable to a new instance of another class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on a Ruby on Rails 6 project, and I am trying to use a [class instance variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15773552/ruby-class-instance-variable-vs-class-variable) on an ActiveRecord model. Here is a basic example:

```rb
class Model << ApplicationRecord
  @var = AnotherClass.new
  
  class << self
    attr_reader :var
  end
  
  # ...
end
```

I would then like to be able to use `Model.var` to access `Model`'s instance of `AnotherClass`. There are multiple such models, each of them referring to a different `AnotherClass`, with all the `AnotherClass`es being subclasses of some `BaseClass`.

However, I am encountering the following error:

> uninitialized constant Model::AnotherClass

Because of the `class << self`, Ruby seems to be looking for a nested class.

Is there a way to access `AnotherClass` directly, or is there a better way in general to set this up?

**Edit**: I solved this with a completely different approach, however I'm still interested to see how you would get around this issue.

Comment: The error you encounter is telling you that the constant `AnotherClass` is not found. Are you sure that is is loaded? Where is `AnotherClass` located? Anything in `lib/` is not covered by the autoloader and you will need to `require 'another_class'` first in those scenarios (or add it to the autoload path).

Comment: @3limin4t0r Thanks, I discovered this about ten 10 seconds before you posted the comment. ;) If you post an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you receive:

> uninitialized constant Model::AnotherClass

Tells you that `AnotherClass` is not initialized (not loaded/found). Let me use the following context as an example:

```
class Model
  AnotherClass
end
```

Ruby will start a constant lookup. This will start from the current namespace (`Model`) and and if nothing is found move up into the namespace tree. In the above example it will first look for `Model::AnotherClass` if that cannot be found it will look for `AnotherClass`, if that cannot be found it will throw the exception you receive.

This error simply tells you that `AnotherClass` is not loaded.

Anything in th `app/` directory is loaded by the autoloader of Rails, however if you use the `lib/` directory you have to manually `require 'another_class'` or add the relevant path to the [autoload paths](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#autoload-paths).

Comment: This explains a lot. I didn't realize that Ruby will first look for `Model::AnotherClass` *before* `AnotherClass`. I solved this by moving the `lib/` directory to `app/lib/` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38198668/rails-5-load-lib-files-in-production).

Comment: @JacobLockard alternatively, you can precede a constant with `::` to make Ruby look for it at the top-level, i.e. `::AnotherClass`

Comment: @Stefan That would normally work, but it didn't in my case because `another_class.rb` was not being loaded by Rails at all.