# How to implement a hierachy or sub-modules that all work within Rails workers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Right now, I have a helper that contains about 1k+ lines of code. I am looking to move all of these methods into a subfolder within `lib/custom/scripts/parsers/`, but I'm not quite sure what changes I need to make to my workers so that I can continue to use all of these methods without an overly complicated process.

For example, I would like to put all of my methods into multiple files such as this:

- lib/custom/scripts/parsers/ip_address_parser.rb
- lib/custom/scripts/parsers/parser_two.rb
- lib/custom/scripts/parsers/parser_three.rb

If I have a method, called `hello_world` inside of `parser_two.rb`, such as:

```
# lib/custom/scripts/parsers/parser_two.rb

module ParserTwo
   def hello_world
      puts "Hello World"
   end
end
```

I would like to be able to directly access the method from the worker, such as:

```
class RandomWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options queue: Rails.env.to_sym, retry: 1

  def perform
    -> how to access hello_world method directly from parser_two.rb?
  end
end
```

Is there a way that I could just have a way to incorporate all of the modules within the `lib/custom/scripts/parsers` directory, and is there a way I can apply this inheritance to all of the workers?

When using helpers, I just do `include HelperName` and that's it, but it doesn't work the same in this scenario of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so what you can do is use `ActiveSupport::Concern` and nest modules inside modules like this:

```
module ParserTwo
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    def hello_world
      puts "hello world!"
    end

    #...other methods
  end
end

module AllParsers
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  
  included do
    include ParserOne
    include ParserTwo
  end
end
```

then you can use `AllParsers` like that:

```
class RandomWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  include AllParsers

  def perform
    hello_world
  end
end
```

still you maintain the ability to use just one module if needed:

```
class RandomWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  include ParserTwo

  def perform
    hello_world
  end
end
```

Now about where to place them.
If you want to place the modules inside the `lib/something/directory` you need to remember to load them properly. You can refer to this stackoverflow question:

[Rails 5: Load lib files in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38198668/rails-5-load-lib-files-in-production)

Comment: I actually did something very similar to what you just mentioned with the exception of `ActiveSupport::Concern`. Everything else is pretty much exact same way. Thanks a lot!